# Less using Web Essentials

Tags: javascript, html, css, less, web-essentials

I'm going to use .less in my css.

Based on my understanding there different kind of way to use .less.

1. you can pre-compile it then use the css generated by .less
2. another one is using this scripts below:

This

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.7.3/less.min.js"></script>
```

as for my understanding it doesn't need the css file because it will generate one for itself once it runs.

---

I've already installed Web Essentials and it is easy to follow number 1 because it generates the file already when you save it or build it. However, I'm planning to use number 2.

I've read: "Web Essentials uses the node-less compiler and it always uses the latest version" so I don't think I need to install anything.

When I run it i got this error:
**FileError: _http://localhost:xxxxxx/Content/style.less wasn't found (404)**

Actually, the VS intellisense can't even find the .less file when I put it in **href=""** so I code it anyway.

---

I've already look into these no one setup in Visual Studio Web Essentials.

- http://verekia.com/less-css/dont-read-less-css-tutorial-highly-addictive
- http://www.sitepoint.com/a-comprehensive-introduction-to-less/
- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/get-into-less-the-programmable-stylesheet-language--webdesign-5216
- http://lesscss.org/#using-less

Comment: You can also use dotless.dll and define settings in web config

Answer (score 1):

It's because IIS doesn't know what a `.less` file is and therefore won't serve it. You need to add the following to your web.config's `<system.webServer>` section:

`<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".less" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
</staticContent>`

Comment: hey, I know that you developed the grunt task runner for vs 2013, so an answer from you will be very valuable of what I'm doing, can you take a peak to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233301/how-to-bind-a-custom-event-to-the-grunt-task-runner-in-vs-2013 thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2014/04/29/refactoring-your-css-with-less-in-visual-studio-web-essentials.aspx) tutorial. You have to include your css file. Some tools like [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) generate your css file to output folder ( Web Essentials do it too).
You have to include generated css.
If you are using less.js you have to set options in server side ([that](http://lesscss.org/) you see in this webpage).
[dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm planning to use number 2.

I would definitely advise against using the `less.js` file as a script on your page.  This will slow your page down as you have to download the js file and then it has to process your less file.  As you are using Visual Studio and Web Essentials this is totally unnecessary, it will compile the CSS file for you.

Web Essentials automatically compiles a CSS file for you either on save or build depending on your settings.  All you then need to do is add the CSS file to your page and **NOT** the less file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

More info on settings within Web Essentials for less can be found on the Web Essentials site.

[Less features](http://vswebessentials.com/features/less)

Comment: Hi Colin! yeah you're right. However, if I wanted to add a feature in my web that will edit my variables in less, will it be updated? even though the build and save is only done in Visual Studio?

Comment: @user1960948 I think you would need to go into more detail as to what you actually want to do.  Maybe that isn't in the scope of this question and should possibly be a separate question.