# How to bind a custom event to the grunt task runner in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, gruntjs

I'm aware of the [task runner](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx) as a visual studio [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708), you can bind a grunt task to a specific visual studio "event" like:

- before build
- after build
- clean
- open solution

In my case I want to **automate the deploy process** to run a **build task** using grunt (clean, minify, concat files, etc.) before creating a **deploy package** when publishing a website in **visual studio**.

I also want to do some modifications to the deploy package **instead** to **pickup** the whole list of files in the **main directory** I'd like to select the libraries (DLLs) and the files that are created by the grunt task in the **dist folder**, for me sounds like a combination of the task runner and the MSBuild.

in other words, these are my questions:

- how can I trigger a task before publishing a website?
- how can I choose specific folders, instead of the whole root directory of the application?

any suggestions or guidance will be more than welcome.

Comment: Are you using standalone msbuild script for that automation ? What is "deploy package" in your case - is this an output from app.publish folder or some sort of package that is not part of VS ?

Comment: the deploy package is the zip file that VS creates after I publish the website that I store locally in my dev machine, this file is shipped with all the files on my root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with *part* of your question, as I'm doing something similar when it comes to selecting what to deploy.

You can create a file in your project called *projectname*.wpp.targets which is an XML file that allows you fine tune MSBuild. [More info here about the MSBuild schema here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx).

I suspect what you're looking for are the ExcludeFromPackageFolders and ExcludeFromPackageFiles, so you only deploy what you want.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="Application;bower_components;node_modules">
        <FromTarget>PhoneBook.wpp.targets</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include=".bowerrc;bower.json;gulpfile.js;package.json;main.html;PhoneBook.wpp.targets">
        <FromTarget>PhoneBook.wpp.targets</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

As for triggering a custom event, sorry I can't help there, I'd love to have a post-publish event to hook into as Gulp and MSBuild can sometimes trip up over each other due to the former's asynchronous nature.